# How to view your app in SAP BTP Cockpit Launchpad, (SAP Build Workzone)

Tags: sap-btp-sdk-ios

I'm having problems in the [image: SAP BTP Cockpit Launchpad, (SAP Build Workzone)]. Basically I have my app that I can view and therefore it opens correctly when I enter the URL in the browser, so then I created a new app inside the launchpad, in the content manager and I entered the URL, but then going in JobCore and opening my app, unfortunately I get a screen that says "connection denied". So my problem is that I can view my app outside of the launchpad while by inserting it into the build workzone I can't see it. I'm posting some screenshots to help you understand better.